# About ElementUI, how to change bg-color of <el-submenu> when hovering it

Tags: vue.js

In elementUI, I've got a `el-menu` component and there is a `el-submenu` in it,
I can change the bg-color of `el-menu-item` when I hover it and I code like

```
.el-menu-item:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color:white
}
```

however when I do the same to the `el-submenu`, it failed

```
.el-submenu:hover{
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
}
```

I tried another way

```
.el-submenu.is-opened {
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
}
```

also can't work

it appears like that
[image]

and I want to change the bg-color when I hover the submenu and when it is open

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that you can do the following to change the background color when hovering over a `el-submenu`:

```
.el-submenu__title:hover {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
```